# JQuery - searching HTML table - rowspan issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, html-table

I have an HTML table of similar structure to this, however:

- rowspans are not of fixed size
- there can be multiple rowspans in a given table (where each can be of different length)
- the table is generated

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruHjT/1/)

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="searchbox">Search:</label>
                <input type="text" id="filter1" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="foo" border="1px">
    <tr> 
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1" rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td class="col1">v</td>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Searching is done using the first column. I'm running into trouble with rowspan when using this search/filter function described below:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {    
     $('#filter1').change(function() { 
     $("#foo td.col1:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent().show();
     $("#foo td.col1:not(:contains('" + $(this).val() + "'))").parent().hide();
     }); 
  });
</script>
```

The problem is when inputting a search term that would hide all rows from **'1'** (such as searching for **'v'**) - only the first row of the rowspan is hidden, whilst all subsequent rows part of the rowspan remain. So row [6,7,8,9] will always remain.

Example table:

> ```
> [1 - 2,3,4,5]
> [  - 6,7,8,9]
> [v - w,x,y,z]
> ```

Searching '**1**' (correct):

> ```
> [1 - 2,3,4,5]
> [  - 6,7,8,9]
> ```

Searching '**v**' (incorrect):

> ```
> [  - 6,7,8,9]  <- this row should not be returned 
> [v - w,x,y,z]
> ```

How do I go about properly hiding those sub rowspans?

**Update:**
I think the solution lies with adding different classes depending on the rowspan count, then having a function that handles these classes differently with an appropriate number of .parent().next(i).hide() - though I'm not sure how to do this and whether this approach is even correct.

Comment: your fiddle does not appear to work for me on chrome

Comment: btw, your table html is not valid (though maybe just in this example) you should have a `thead` element there in `#foo`

Comment: @mkoryak That's because you haven't chosen to run it with jQuery enabled on the side on jsFiddle :)

Comment: its because i was expecting a working fiddle with everything ready to go :) - ill update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rowspan`ed `td`s aren't children of all the `tr` elements that they seem to belong to. All element in the DOM tree may only have one direct parent, in your case it's the direct `tr` parent shown in the HTML.

With that in mind, I'd recommend making your design with `div`s or such, which would allow you to do such operations much more naturally.

Anyway without having to change your HTML, you can do some compensations with the row index and its `rowspan` attribute, check if it is of use:

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter1').change(function() {
        var toShow = $("#data td.col1:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')");
        $("#data tr").not( $('#data tr').has(toShow) ).hide();
        toShow.each(function() {
            var rspan = $(this).attr('rowspan'),
                father = $(this).parent();
            if (rspan && +rspan > 1) {
                father.nextUntil(':nth-child(' + (father.index() + (+rspan) + 1) + ')').andSelf().show();
            } else father.show();
        });
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruHjT/4/)